# IEnumerable cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: asp.net, linq

I would like to use a data list for showing the usernames and their comments and attachments for each comment below the user name.

I have a user control `ReviewList`for showing the comments and `efiles` in that. But I have error in this line (s.tblDraft.Comments) and an error below:

```
The non-generic type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' cannot be used with type arguments
```

Please help. What is the problem?

```
private void Displayuser()
{
    var reviews =
      (from s in _DataContext.tblSends
       from u in _DataContext.Users

       where (s.DraftId == _Draftid) && (s.ToEmailId == u.ID)
       orderby u.Name
       select new
{
    userid = u.ID,
    username = u.Name,
    comments =s.tblDraft.Comments,
    w = s.tblDraft.Comments.SelectMany(q => q.CommentAttaches)

}).Distinct();

    DataList1.DataSource = reviews;
    DataList1.DataBind();

    var theReview = reviews.Single();

    DisplayReviews(theReview.comments, theReview.w);
}

private void DisplayReviews(IEnumerable<Comment> comments,
     IEnumerable<CommentAttach> w)
{
    ReviewList reviewList = (ReviewList)DataList1.FindControl("ReviewList1");
    reviewList.Comments = comments;
    reviewList.CommentAttachs = w;
    reviewList.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The type the compiler sees is [`System.Collections.IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) which is the non generic IEnumerable. You imported that namespace, so this is the type the compiler thinks you're trying to use.

The type you're trying to use is [`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx). Add an import of that namespace and things should compile.

Comment: Good stuff! Also, if you use a tool like Resharper, it would suggest this fix for you.

Comment: Hi Joachim, i tried "using  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>" but it says "The type or namespace name `T' could not be found." any idea?

Comment: @Michimcchicken T is just a placeholder for a real type in the declaration. For example, if you want an IEnumerable of string, you should just use `IEnumerable<string>`, an IEnumerable of integers, `IEnumerable<int>` etc.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add an import of the namespace:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Comment: @GertArnold I am new in .NET. So it was not obvious to me what should be the using statement from the accepted answer.

Comment: This was indeed the answer for me in blazor land.